# pylance, linting not working in vscode python venv

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtualenv, pylance

I am trying to get pylance and linting work in vscode with the virtualenv I created. It works outside the virtualenv perfectly. After a lot of inspections I finally found this error on `Log(Extension Host)`: `[error] [ms-python.python] provider FAILED`. This occured when I tried to rename a variable.

I have cross checked the settings multiple times with the official website but nothing worked.

I am working on Windows 10 with the latest stable version of vscode.

EDIT: I just deleted .vscode and reloaded vscode, and linting is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you create a separate answer and move the "EDIT" there? (You can also mark it as an answer after).